# Python 3 division inaccurate

Tags: python-3.x

```
>>> 1.4 / 7
0.19999999999999998
```

Why??

I would like to get 0.2, so the issue is not the Python2 to Python3 int/float division change.
Is there any solution other than using Decimal?

Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AM
D64)] on win32

Comment: And it's not limited to division.

`>>> 0.2 + 0.1 : 0.30000000000000004`

Comment: I don't remember Python 2.x having such problems

Comment: just checked on 2.7 - same

Answer (score 1):

Because 1.4 is not represented as 1.4 but as `1.39999999999999991118` in double precision floating point arithmetic (with 20 digits output precision). You can either use the `Decimal` type or round when you format the output (`"%.1f" % 1.4` vs. `"%.20f" % 1.4`)

Comment: Decimal won't solve it either, and I need the value not the string.

Comment: >>> Decimal(1.4) / 7
Decimal('0.1999999999999999873117368614')
>>> Decimal(1.4) / Decimal(7.0)
Decimal('0.1999999999999999873117368614')
>>>

Comment: Try `from decimal import Decimal; Decimal('1.4')/7`

Comment: right! thanks @W.Mann

Answer (score 0):

You can use `round(1.4/7,10)` I will suggest check the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: That won't change the problem. `0.2`is not decimal number 0.2 but 0.20000000000000001110 (rounded to 20 digits) in double precision floating point arithmetic.

Comment: I am unable to understand the problem here this is binary to decimal representation change the type if you are not comfortable with float type data.